# Selecting newest row for every id in Laravel's Eloquent

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I have a history of every rental of a book from the library and based on that I want to show current status of ALL BOOKS in the library. If I have `only id`, `book_id`, `status` (bool), and `timestamps`. How should I do it in the easiest way without touching SQL? I want to have the freshest record for every `book_id` for example:

```
|--|-------|------|----------|
|id|book_id|status|timestamp-|
|--|-------|------|----------|
| 1|      1|     0|12.12.2019|
| 2|      2|     0|13.12.2019|
| 3|      3|     0|14.12.2019|
| 4|      2|     1|15.12.2019|
| 5|      3|     1|16.12.2019|
| 6|      3|     0|17.12.2019|
|--|-------|------|----------|
```

and I want to get this:

```
|--|-------|------|----------|
|id|book_id|status|timestamp-|
|--|-------|------|----------|
| 1|      1|     0|12.12.2019|
| 4|      2|     1|15.12.2019|
| 6|      3|     0|17.12.2019|
|--|-------|------|----------|
```

Ideas?

Comment: Can you show the table schema, What is the datatype of `timestamp-`?

Comment: Did you get any problem with the answers listed below?

Answer (score 1):

Create a relation `bookHistories` inside `Book` model

//If you need to retrieve every book histories

```
public function bookHistories(){
    return $this->hasMany(BookHistory::class, 'book_id');
}
```

//If you need to retrieve only one latest book history

```
public function latestBookHistory(){
    return $this->hasOne(BookHistory::class, 'book_id')->orderByDesc('timestamp');
}
```

Now you can get latest book history of all books like:

//Using with will eagar load latest book history to optimize code

```
$books = Book::with('latestBookHistory')->get();
```

Now you use latest book history as your necessary

```
foreach($books as $book){
    $latestBookHistory = $book->latestBookHistory;
    // If incase the latest book history is empty for the current book
    if(!empty($latestBookHistory){
        //Checking book history status of latest
        dd($latestBookHistory->status);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### You can use [`Laravel Collections`](https://laravel.com/docs/collections) and it's [`last()`](https://laravel.com/docs/collections#method-last) method:

**Example:**

```
$data = ModelName::all();
$last_data_object = collect($data)->last();

//try to see the object using var_dump()
var_dump($last_data_object);
```

Answer (score 0):

The relation for getting all the history of a book in your Book model

```
public function bookHistories(){
    return $this->hasMany(BookHistory::class, 'book_id');
}
```

Make the relation for getting latest record against every book

```
public function latestBookHistory(){
    return $this->bookHistories()->latest();
}
```

Check form your controller

```
$books = Book::all();
foreach($books as $book){
    if(!empty($book->$latestBookHistory) {
        //Which would return a collection, so still you have to call first()
        $latest = $book->latestBookHistory->first();
        dd($latest->id, $latest->book_id, $latest->status, $latest->created_at);
    }
}
```